# Dynamic assignment of input variables for Pine script 4.0

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to assign the default ATR Resolution to be the same as the current Chart being used. So,

- if I was on a Weekly chart, the `default input` ATR Resolution would
  be 'W'
- if I was on a Daily chart, the `default input` ATR Resolution would
  be 'D'
- etc.

Pseudocode I am trying to write:

```
timeframe = '1'
current = timeframe.period
if current != timeframe
    timeframe = current

i_atrRes  = input(defval=timeframe, type=input.resolution, title='ATR Resolution', group="STOP LOSS - used only if 'ATR' selected")
```

I have been looking at information on this link:
https://backtest-rookies.com/2019/03/15/tradingview-daily-atr-stop/

```
This is what I have encountered so far ...
timeframe = "'" + timeframe.period  + "'"   < --- does not work
timeframe = "'" + tostring(1)  + "'"        < --- does not work
timeframe = '1'                             < --- works
```

for the statement below:

> i_atrRes  = input(defval=timeframe, type=input.resolution, title='ATR
> Resolution', group="STOP LOSS - used only if 'ATR' selected")

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
i_atrRes  = input('', type=input.resolution)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.